# Why am I getting errors about strings when all my data is numeric

Tags: python, scikit-learn

```
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer

categorical = [col for col in X.columns
              if X[col].dtypes == 'object']
numerical = list(set(X.columns) - set(categorical))

numerical_processes = make_pipeline(SimpleImputer(strategy = 'constant', fill_value = 0), StandardScaler())
categorical_processes = make_pipeline(SimpleImputer(strategy = 'constant', fill_value = 'None'), OrdinalEncoder())

X[numerical] = numerical_processes.fit_transform(X[numerical])
X[categorical] = categorical_processes.fit_transform(X[categorical])
```

Here's the code I used to preprocess my data. For reference I am trying to calculate Mutual Information for features in a dataset where the target are house sale prices.

```
from sklearn.feature_selection import mutual_info_regression
def MI(X, y, categorical):
    mi_score = mutual_info_regression(X, y, discrete_features = categorical)
    mi_score = pd.Series(mi_score, name = 'Mutual Info', index = X.columns)
    return mi_score
```

This is the function I used to calculate Mutual Information.

```
mi_scores = MI(X, y, categorical)
print(mi_scores)
```

I should be getting a pandas series with the mutual information score for each column in the dataframe X, but I get this error instead:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[21], line 1
----> 1 mi_scores = MI(X, y, categorical)
      2 print(mi_scores)

Cell In[15], line 3, in MI(X, y, categorical)
      2 def MI(X, y, categorical):
----> 3     mi_score = mutual_info_regression(X, y, discrete_features = categorical)
      4     mi_score = pd.Series(mi_score, name = 'Mutual Info', index = X.columns)
      5     return mi_score

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/feature_selection/_mutual_info.py:388, in mutual_info_regression(X, y, discrete_features, n_neighbors, copy, random_state)
    312 def mutual_info_regression(
    313     X, y, *, discrete_features="auto", n_neighbors=3, copy=True, random_state=None
    314 ):
    315     """Estimate mutual information for a continuous target variable.
    316 
    317     Mutual information (MI) [1]_ between two random variables is a non-negative
   (...)
    386            of a Random Vector", Probl. Peredachi Inf., 23:2 (1987), 9-16
    387     """
--> 388     return _estimate_mi(X, y, discrete_features, False, n_neighbors, copy, random_state)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/feature_selection/_mutual_info.py:267, in _estimate_mi(X, y, discrete_features, discrete_target, n_neighbors, copy, random_state)
    265     discrete_mask.fill(discrete_features)
    266 else:
--> 267     discrete_features = check_array(discrete_features, ensure_2d=False)
    268     if discrete_features.dtype != "bool":
    269         discrete_mask = np.zeros(n_features, dtype=bool)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py:910, in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, estimator, input_name)
    902         raise ValueError(
    903             "Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:\narray={}.\n"
    904             "Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if "
    905             "your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) "
    906             "if it contains a single sample.".format(array)
    907         )
    909 if dtype_numeric and array.dtype.kind in "USV":
--> 910     raise ValueError(
    911         "dtype='numeric' is not compatible with arrays of bytes/strings."
    912         "Convert your data to numeric values explicitly instead."
    913     )
    914 if not allow_nd and array.ndim >= 3:
    915     raise ValueError(
    916         "Found array with dim %d. %s expected <= 2."
    917         % (array.ndim, estimator_name)
    918     )

ValueError: dtype='numeric' is not compatible with arrays of bytes/strings.Convert your data to numeric values explicitly instead.
```

I have tried so many times to preprocess my data and I have double checked every time. I encoded all categorical variables and imputed missing values. I imputed missing values for numeric variable too and ran them through a standard scaler. How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As specified in the documentation available [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.mutual_info_regression.html),

> the **discrete_features** parameter *should be either a boolean mask
> with shape (n_features,) or **array with indices** of discrete
> features*.

This is how it works:

```
from sklearn.feature_selection import mutual_info_regression
def MI(X, y, categorical):
    mi_score = mutual_info_regression(X, 
                                      y.values.ravel(), 
                                      discrete_features= X.columns.get_indexer(categorical), 
                                      random_state=42)
    mi_score = pd.Series(mi_score, name = 'Mutual Info', index = X.columns)
    return mi_score
```

- I've also modified `y.values.ravel()` so that the target variable `y` is a 1D array (a vector) rather than a DataFrame column.
- Finally, I've added `random_state=42` for reproducible results

With this, you should have no more worries about estimating your mutual information.